Is there a way to hide the bottom of the navigation drawer
My navigation drawer is visible behind the default footer of the phone (back button, home button, recent apps button). My 
I want the default footer to hide the navigation drawer. I don't want to hide the default footer as I have overwritten the function onbackpressed().

I guess you have this line of code inside onCreate() in your Activity class:
enableEdgeToEdge()

Just remove it
